# Makefile doesn't find the rule

Tags: c, makefile, path

I have to do a makefile to compile something, but I got a problem : when I type the make command, I got an error message saying that there is no rules for one of the targets. The problem is about the path to the target, using an environment var.

Here is the given start of the Makefile :

```
    CC = mipsel-unknown-elf-gcc
AS = mipsel-unknown-elf-as
LD = mipsel-unknown-elf-ld
DU = mipsel-unknown-elf-objdump

SYS_OBJS = reset.o \
           giet.o \
           common.o \
           ctx_handler.o \
           drivers.o \
           exc_handler.o \
           irq_handler.o \
           sys_handler.o

APP_OBJS = stdio.o main.o

GIET ?= /(my path)/giet

SYS_PATH = $(GIET)/sys
APP_PATH = $(GIET)/app

SYS_CFLAGS = -Wall -ffreestanding -mno-gpopt -mips32 -I$(SYS_PATH) -I.
APP_CFLAGS = -Wall -ffreestanding -mno-gpopt -mips32 -I$(APP_PATH) -I.

all: sys.bin app.bin
```

(I am supposed to finish it)

What I tried to do (rule for sys.bin works fine) :

```
common.o: common.c
    mipsel-unknown-elf-gcc $(SYS_CFLAGS) common.o $(SYS_PATH)/common.c
```

The command I'm using to compile myself is : mipsel-unknown-elf-gcc -ffreestanding -mno-gpopt -mips32 -I$GIET/sys  -I. -c -o common.o $GIET/sys/common.c 
Could you help me to fix this ?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a `-o` (output file specifier) at the end of `$(SYS_CFLAGS)` *or* before the `common.o` in the command for your rule. That's the important difference between your `makefile` and your manual command.

Without that specifier, it will try to *act* on `common.o` rather than produce it, attempting to combine both `common.o` and `$(SYS_PATH)/common.c` into (most likely) `a.out`.

To fix it, change the rule to:

```
common.o: common.c
    mipsel-unknown-elf-gcc $(SYS_CFLAGS) -o common.o $(SYS_PATH)/common.c
    #                                    ^^
    #              Add this bit here (but not these two comment lines).
```

Comment: It doesn't work (I had already tried `common.o: common.c
  mipsel-unknown-elf-gcc -ffreestanding -mno-gpopt -mips32 -I$GIET/sys  -I. -c -o common.o $GIET/sys/common.c`).

Comment: @xDra, the cause of your immediate problem is almost certainly the missing `-o`. If, after you fix that, you have another problem, you should ask *another* question, adding more detail on what the problem is (rather than just stating "it doesn't work").

Comment: The error output is the same : there is no rules to create common.c. It's why I think that the problem is about the path.